# For loop on span who create one div

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I have multiple span in my project and I want to take the content of each span and put into one div.

I tried this but it put only the last span..
Thanks in advance

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll("li span");
const div = document.querySelector("div");
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
const span = document.createElement("span");

for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  const item = items[i];
  const content = item.textContent;

  span.textContent = content;
  div.appendChild(span);
  ul.remove();
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><span>One</span></li>
    <li><span>Two</span></li>
    <li><span>Three</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: from the `appendChild` docs: "If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position"

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new span each time. Move your `const span = document.createElement("span");` inside the loop

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll("li span");
const div = document.querySelector("div");
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  const span = document.createElement("span");
  const item = items[i];
  const content = item.textContent;
  span.textContent = content;
  div.appendChild(span);
  ul.remove();
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><span>One</span></li>
    <li><span>Two</span></li>
    <li><span>Three</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect but this solution create 3 span in line..
How do the same but in only one div ?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English.. your solution create 3 spans in the div, I want just the content off all span in the div

Comment: So you don't want any spans in the div? Just the content of ths spans? Like https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xmrmo41c/?

Comment: I want a div with only one text who contain the three span like that: <div>OneTwoThree</div> 
And not 
<div><span>One</span><span>Two<span>Three</span></div>

Comment: That's what the fiddle in my last comment does. The result is `<div>OneTwoThree</div>`

Comment: Do you know how to add <br /> for separate each content ?

Comment: It's ok I just changed textContent with innerHTML like that : 
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML +"<br>"+ content;

Answer (score 0):

You are only creating one span and re-using it. Create a new span each iteration.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll("li span");
const div = document.querySelector("div");
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");

for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  const item = items[i];
  const content = item.textContent;
  const span = document.createElement("span");
  span.textContent = content;
  div.appendChild(span);
  ul.remove();
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><span>One</span></li>
    <li><span>Two</span></li>
    <li><span>Three</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but how do the same but with all content on 1 div ? not 3 span in one div..

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `ul.remove()` inside of the loop at least.
and besides that you need to create the div within the loop. Otherwise you overwrite it.

Check the code. Result: 3 divs. Each of them with a span inside.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll("li span");
const divContainer = document.querySelector("div");
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");

ul.remove();
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  const item = items[i];
  const content = item.textContent;
  divContainer.innerHTML += content;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><span>One</span></li>
    <li><span>Two</span></li>
    <li><span>Three</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the OP removes the `ul` because.. the OP wants to remove that `ul` ;)

Comment: Well if he wants to remove the node its enough to remove it once and not inside of the loop. The second time there is no `ul` to remove.

Comment: Why are you giving an answer that doesn't benefit the op??? They Specifically said that they wanted to remove the ul

Comment: @ElectroxQuiMortem I think you should read the OP again carefully.

Comment: Thank you but how do the same thing but put the 3 contents in one div ? In the same content.. do you understand ?
Not 3 spans content in 1 div, but 1 div with 1 content

Comment: @Flosrn then you just append the `span` directly without wrapping it before in a div. I updated the snippet in my answer.

Comment: It not do exactly what I want. In fact I want a div with only one text who contain the three span like that:
<div>OneTwoThree</div>
And not <div><span>One</span><span>Two<span>Three</span></div>

Comment: @Flosrn well then you cant use appendChild since thats only for nodes. I updated my answer snippet!

Comment: Thanks and for better design I add br : div.innerHTML += "<br>" + content;

Comment: Well adding <br> tags has nothing to do with "good design". But that might be another topic. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You did this incorrectly. You created the span outside of the for loop, meaning there is only one span

```
<body>
    <div id="div">
      <ul id="ul">
        <li><span class="span">One</span></li>
        <li><span class="span">Two</span></li>
        <li><span class="span">Three</span></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        const items = document.getElementsByClassName("span");
        const div = document.querySelector("div");
        const ul = document.getElementById("ul");
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            const item = items[i];
            const content = item.textContent;
            var span = document.createElement("span");
            var br = document.createElement("br")
            span.textContent = content;
            div.appendChild(br)
            div.appendChild(span);
        }
        div.removeChild(ul)
    </script>
</body>
```